# How to create a mix and match configurable product option?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-community

I am trying to create a mix and match product but cant work out how to do it! The product is a two piece bikini.

For any one Bikini Set for example there will be in stock:-

Top Size

2 x size 6, 2 x size 8, 2 x size 10, 2 x size 12, etc

Bottom Size

2 x size 6, 2 x size 8, 2 x size 10, 2 x size 12, etc

The customer can select any top size that they want and any bottom size that they want. So they can go Size 12 Top, Size 6 Bottom, when they order that however I need it to delete the stock total of both the top and the bottom. Eventually the shop could be left with 1 size 8 top and 1 size 14 bottom but the whole concept of the store is mix and match.

How is it best to set up this product?

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by using separate configurable products for the tops and bottoms. I would then use related products so the customer can easily find the tops/bottoms.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a custom view to list simple products, if the simple product is not individually visible, it can be added to the shopping cart by programming, when the customer chooses size or color and add to shopping cart you add every single elected by programming.